# Checking if view controller has been loaded before

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to checking if a certain view has been loaded ever before in the lifetime of the app. I have implemented the following code but not quite sure why it isn't working. It is being done in the viewDidLoad method only of the view controller (perhaps this is the problem). If anyone can let me know what my mistake is, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 BOOL hasRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstRun"];
                     if (hasRunBefore) {
                         NSLog (@"not the very first time this controller has been loaded");
                          [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstRun"];
                         [defaults synchronize];
                     }
                     else if (!hasRunBefore) {
                         [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstRun"];
                          NSLog (@"the very first time this controller has been loaded");
                         [defaults synchronize];
                     }
```

Comment: By lifetime, do you mean 1) Between installing the app and uninstalling it, 2) Between application start and application terminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code. See the corrections below:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL hasRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstRun"];

if (hasRunBefore) {
    NSLog (@"not the very first time this controller has been loaded");
    /* Toggle the boolean state */
    [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstRun"];
}
else if (!hasRunBefore) {
    /* Toggle the boolean state */
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstRun"];
    NSLog (@"the very first time this controller has been loaded");
}
[defaults synchronize];
```

However, I am not sure why you would want to toggle the FirstRun back to NO in the if(hasRunBefore). I only point out what is wrong, you might want to check your logic again.

-EDIT-
Like I pointed out about your logic, you should only have this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL hasRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstRun"];

if (!hasRunBefore) {
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstRun"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog (@"the very first time this controller has been loaded");
}
else
    NSLog (@"Not the first time this controller has been loaded");
```

Comment: Here is the issue Rick perhaps you know what is going on. I made the changes you suggested and then I removed the app from my device, ran it again through xcode and it says "very first time loaded..." as it should. I stop the app from running and run it again, this time it says "Not the very first time..." AGAIN as it should. Now this when things get strange, I try running the app a 3rd time and it says "this is the first time..." which is a mistake. Do you know why? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The values set in defaults are persistent for as long as the app is installed on the device.

You should think about using a BOOL value set in the app delegate (which does not persist from run to run)

OR

You should set "FirstRun" back to NO in your app delegate in the following method.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is a possibility, but you could also use a static `BOOL` and set it to `YES` when the view controller is loaded for the first time.